# Analytical form of a joint PDF of two uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: statistics

I was wondering if it is possible to write down (closed-form analytically) the joint density function of two uniformly distributed random variables ($X$ and $Y$, each on a closed interval $dX=x_2-x_1$ & $dY=y_2-y_1$) as a function of the correlation coefficient.

E.g. $f(X)=1/dX$ and $f(Y)=1/dY \Rightarrow$ support set of $f(X,Y)$ is between $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$.

This picture on wikipedia shows the correlation on such a rectangle graphically: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#mediaviewer/File:Correlation_examples2.svg

Is it possible to find a closed form analytical expression of $f(X,Y)$ as a function of the correlation coefficient? Furthermore, can we express $f(X+Y)$?

Comment: The facts that X and Y are uniform on known intervals and the value of their correlation rho do not determine their joint density (except when rho=+1 or rho=-1).

Comment: Ok, I understand that. Is it possible then to find a (one of the infinitely many) closed form expression of f(X,Y)? (or directly f(X+Y), the one I am looking for)

Comment: You could consider the independent case.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you are talking about [copulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29). There are a lot of them, but they allows you to specify a joint distribution with uniform marginals.

Answer (score 0):

By running the following Matlab code I more or less understood copulas and the inverse cumulative function trick they use. But from reading the Wikipedia page I still don't understand how to find a closed form analytical one (if possible). (Sorry for starting a new answer, I was not able to comment and my guest account did not work)
xh=1000;
xl=500;
dx=xh-xl;
yh=400;
yl=200;
dy=yh-yl;

n = 100;
rho = 0.8;
nu = 1;
T = mvtrnd([1 rho; rho 1], nu, n);
U = tcdf(T,nu);
X = [gaminv(U(:,1),2,1) tinv(U(:,2),5)];
figure
plot(xl+U(:,1)*dx,yl+U(:,2)*dy,'.');

Comment: Look at archimedian copulas. They have explicit forms. Take the mixed derivative of the copula to get the joint pdf.

Answer (score -3):

$\frac{1}{(d(b-a)-c(b-a))}$ for two joint uniform random variables $X$ and $Y$ ranging from $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$, respectively. You can check by integrating the formula to $1$.